# py-autopep8-enable-on-save is deprecated! use [py-autopep8-mode] instead!

Tags: python, elpy

I'm getting the message

```
py-autopep8-enable-on-save is deprecated! use [py-autopep8-mode] instead!
```

in the messages on startup. How to properly update it?

GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using elpy then updating your .emacs file fixes this.

```
;; old line (this throws the warning)
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)

;; updated line
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-mode)
```